# Recursive functions with constant parameters

Tags: c++, recursion, pseudocode

In C++ is there a preferred way of dealing with a recursive function that reuses an unchanged object every time? For example (pseudo code):

```
void func(HashMap h, Logger logger, int depth)
{
    // Do stuff then call func recursively...
    func(h, logger, depth+1);
}
```

So every call we pass in several objects (hash map and logger) unchanged. Yes we can pass by reference but it still seems inefficient and doesn't look very pretty. The only alternative I can think of is global variables or bundling up the constant parameters in a struct.

Comment: Well, there are reasons why there are different languages. They all specialize in different use cases, and have fundamental differences. The most optimal solution for one particular language may not be the best solution for another language.

Comment: In C++ bundle up the constant parameters in a struct and pass it by reference

Comment: `Yes we can pass by reference but it still seems inefficient`, pray explain?

Comment: @M.M: No, why should you bundle objects that have nothing to do with each other?

Comment: They are related to each other in that they are requird by the recursive function

Comment: @M.M: I don't think that this is enough. How would you name the struct? HashMapWithLoggerAttached? If you can't come up with a meaningful name for something, it usually is not a good idea to define it.

Comment: @txtechhelp we are putting the same address on the stack over and over again, so it's feels both space and time inefficient. (I relise it's a very small overhead, but it all adds up)

Comment: You can implement move constructor on `Logger` to reduce cost.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a closed lexical environment, aka a "closure". That concept exists "for free" in dynamic languages like Lisp and Scheme, where the "let over lambda" pattern allows you to capture variables in a function and use them even though their enclosing scope is gone or exited.

You can simulate closures in C++ using a `struct` as the container for the captured variables and apply functions (functors) to the `struct`. The most common pattern for this is typically the way that `operator()` is used:

```
struct my_closure {
   Hashmap &hmap_;
   Logger &logger_;
   int depth_;

   my_closure(Hashmap &hmap, Logger &logger, int depth) :
     hmap_(hmap), logger_(logger), depth_(depth)
   { }

   void operator()(void)
   { /* do stuff here, including recurse */ }
};
```

The only thing this will save you is pushing extra stuff on the stack, which doesn't necessarily save you much in terms of cycles (1 struct reference [`this` pointer for the struct] vs. 2 references + 1 integer.) If your compiler supports tail recursion, this could be a benefit at the expense of readability.

Comment: C++11 supports closures. So you don't need to create a dedicated struct (with a silly name) any more.

Comment: @FrankPuffer: It's useful to understand how to create one when you don't have C++11's machinery at your disposal. Inasmuch as understanding that pointers to functions are how to implement virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly clean code that expresses exactly what is happening. Of course in C++ you should pass the HashMap and the Logger as const reference.

From a performance point of view, however it might be better to make these two objects class variables. But this could make the code harder to understand, so just do it if you really have a performance issue.

By the way, what is the function doing if it doesn't modify the HashMap and returns void?

Comment: In my case the hashmap was read only and provided some lookups for the processing in the recursive function.

Comment: @SteevieP: So the main effect of the function is actually a side effect? This is usually not considered a good design, especially for  a recursive function.