# Recursive functions with constant parameters in C++20 or later

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm wondering what the preferred (and most performant) way to deal with constant parameters in recursive functions in C++20 or later is—e.g., consider a recursive function of the form

```cpp
void f(int p, int x) {
    if (someCondition(p, x)) {
        sideEffect;
    } else {
        f(p, g(x));
        f(p, h(x));
    }
}
```

where `p` stays constant over all function calls.

This question [was asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119148/recursive-functions-with-constant-parameters), but was asked **in 2016**. The most-upvoted answer uses a `struct`, but a comment on that answer says:

> C++11 supports closures. So you don't need to create a dedicated struct (with a silly name) any more. – Frank Puffer Mar 21, 2016 at 8:17

suggesting that modern C++ might handle the situation differently. As such, this question is specifically meant to ask about what the best way to accomplish this in modern C++ is (at the time of writing), e.g. C++20 or even C++23.

This question is also written from the perspective of someone who's pretty new to C++! :) For example, I don't really understand how what this commenter is saying applies to a recursive function—are they talking about recursive lambdas as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067988/recursive-lambda-functions-in-c11)? Do you benefit from the same compiler optimizations when compiling a recursive lambda as you would compiling a "normal" recursive function? Or is a different, unmentioned strategy even better for a recursive function of this form?

I care primarily about performance, as my foray into C++ in the first place is motivated by needing to search a large space efficiently.

Any advice (even if tangential to the question) is appreciated. I'm happy to provide more details if this question is underdetermined, but didn't want to make the question too long if I could help it.

---

**More details on the algorithm:** the actual algorithm in question is one for creating Lyndon words (with k = 2) adapted from the source on the [Combinatorial Object Server](http://combos.org/necklace), which in turn implements the algorithm from [this paper](http://www.cis.uoguelph.ca/%7Esawada/papers/un.pdf). However, I want to use `N` and the functions I plan to call in `sideEffect` as constant parameters.

Here's the specific form of the algorithm:

```cpp
// a is a long global array of bools. Maybe there's a better way?
// g will be some kind of side-effectful function that e.g. puts work items in a queue;
// might be more intensive than this algorithm, not sure.
// g and N are constant parameters; t and p vary from call to call.
void Gen(auto g, int N, int t, int p) {
    if(t>N && N == p) {
        // Call `g` and read from `a`, somehow, perhaps via adding to a queue
        sideEffect(g, N, t, p);
    }
    else {
        a[t] = a[t-p]; 
        Gen(g, N, t+1, p);
        if (!(a[t-p])) {
            a[t] = true;
            Gen(g, N, t+1, t);
        }
    };
};
```

I'm inheriting some design choices from the original algorithm, but I'm free to change them; I'm a bit uncomfy with using a global array for `a`, for example, but maybe it's the fastest.

---

Edit: `g(x)` and `h(x)` were previously simply `x-1` and `x+1`, which, as pointed out in the comments, trivializes things.

Comment: For someone new to C++, you seem to have picked up a lot of the subtleties of the different versions very quickly, so definite props for that! In Python or Haskell, I'd use a closure, but in C++ I'd probably still use a `struct`. That explicit Y combinator recursion parameter in the question you linked is a cute trick, but it's not very intuitive.

Comment: Preferred and performant are two different questions. Don't optimize something for performance over legibility unless you know or have very strong reason to think it's a bottleneck of the actual program. Recursive functions do have some issues, though; but it's hard to give a general alternative without a more specific pattern. The `x-1` and `x+1` example isn't helpful because if `someCondition` is pure, the side effect can only happen one, two, or infinity times.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Haha, thanks—I started this journey trying to figure out `constexpr`, which was kind of a trial by fire! :) Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @aschepler I've updated the question with details on the algorithm; I don't know it's a bottleneck, but I do know this algorithm will at least constitute a good part of the computation, as I know the number of times `sideEffect` will be executed will be extremely large. We do know it terminates, however, as `sideEffect` is called exactly as many times as there are length-N Lyndon words on a binary alphabet. But maybe it's still not worth optimizing? Perhaps you can tell from the code & comments. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite nuanced and requires an understanding of ABI. You can assume that an `int`, a reference, and the implicit `this` pointer that is passed to functions (if any) requires one register to pass the information.

#### Simple solution

In your oversimplified example:

> ```cpp
> void f(int p, int x) {
> ```

Even if `p` is constant, it wouldn't be any better to use a lambda or a `struct`, since `p` is taking up one register, and the implicit `this` pointer of a member function does too. You wouldn't save anything performance-wise if `p` was the data member of a class. In fact, you would be adding indirection through the `this` pointer if you used a member function to solve the problem.

In the actual example:

> ```cpp
> void Gen(auto g, int N, int t, int p) {
> ```

`g` is an arbitrary function object, and may be arbitrarily large, and may be expensive to copy. `N` fits into a register. To avoid copying `g`, you can create a second version of `Gen`:

```cpp
// hide this in a detail namespace or a source file
void GemImpl(auto& g, int N, int t, int p); // does what your old Gen did

void Gen(auto g, int N, int t, int p) {
    return GenImpl(g, N, t, p);
}
```

There is no indirection for `N`, `g` does not get copied (only a reference to it is), and `g` is always one level of indirection away. This is likely optimal for performance, although you should still benchmark it to know for sure.

#### Solution using recursive lambdas

An alternative solution is to use recursive lambdas:

```cpp
void Gen(auto g, int N, int t_, int p_) {
    [&g, N](this auto& self, int t, int p) -> void {
        // ...
        self(t + 1, p); // recursive call
        // ...
    }(t_, p_);
}
```

This is slightly less optimal because there are two levels of indirection for `g`, since it is obtained through the `this` pointer of the lambda, which has a reference member. There is also an added level of indirection for `N`. However, an optimizing compiler may eliminate some of this.

Note that prior to C++23, you can use a `struct` obtain the same behavior as the lambda has, with the same ABI and performance properties.

#### Conclusion

Constant parameters may not be the worst thing to have.
You should avoid potentially expensive copies, and as long as you do that, you don't need a recursive lambda or `struct`.

Recursive lambdas don't necessarily improve ABI or performance (in fact, they can make it worse, although you should benchmark this to make sure).
However, they get rid of function parameters and thus improve code quality a bit.
That is, if you don't consider the code quality to suffer from using much more obscure language features.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks so much! Plus, you prompted me to google (and now know about) a useful term/concept (ABI). :)